# Determinar pasta raiz do servidor web no Vagrant

Tags: php, vagrant

Segue meu `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "scotch"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.107"
    config.vm.hostname = "scotchbox"
    config.vm.synced_folder "../public/", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]

    # Optional NFS. Make sure to remove other synced_folder line too
    #config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=666"] }

end
```

Estou fazendo para atender a seguinte estrutura de diretórios:

```
-| D
---| Projetos
-----| PHP
-------| 5
-------| 7
-------| public
```

Onde no diretório PHP, tenho diferentes máquinas com versões do php distintas, e na mesma pasta tenho o `public`, onde irei colocar meus projetos, a ideia é compartilhar esse diretório como se fosse o meu `/var/www` de todas as máquinas, na teoria meu `Vagrantfile` está funcionando, a máquina liga normalmente, mas ao acessar o *IP* dela pelo navegador é dado o `404 Not Found`, o que pode ser?

A saída do meu `vagrant up` é:

```
PS D:\Projetos\PHP\7> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
[default] GuestAdditions 5.1.10 running --- OK.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /var/www => D:/Projetos/PHP/public
    default: /vagrant => D:/Projetos/PHP/7
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

Obs: já determinei permissões para o grupo "Todos" do Windows.

Comment: Tente substituir

config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/Projetos/PHP/public/" 

Depois rode o vagrant provision

Comment: @LuKsSys Continuou a mesma coisa :(

Comment: Complicado... Eu também apanhei muito com o vagrant no ambiente windows, sempre que resolvia um problema aparecia outro, só resolveu tudo quando rodei linux

Comment: @LuKsSys eu usava Linux, voltei por Windows, agora estou usando o Vagrant kk, consegui resolver, era a box que 'concatenava' um 'public' no caminho, dai colocando só ../ deu certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu descobri que a box *scotch*, edita o nome da pasta compartilhada, acrescentando um `/public` ao caminho, logo ficaria:

`D:/Projetos/PHP/public/public`, então eu alterei `../public/` para `../` e funcionou.